# Why my code is receiving an empty or blank value form my input?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

Currently I am learning Ionic using Vue (with previous knowledge od Vue), I am doing some basic activities and was trying to pass the value from an input to the javascript side and show the input text or value inside an alert or in the console, but when I call the method that does it, I only get an empty or blank string as it the input field was empty.

I am using Ionic 4 and Vue.js, in the past I used Vue alone and had no problems with this kind of things.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Floating Label</ion-label>
      <ion-input v-model="input" @keyup.enter="show"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        input: ""
      }
    },
    methods: {
      show() {
        alert(this.input)
      }
    }
  }
 </script>
```

I am expecting the output to be the same value as the input, but in the console I get a blank or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Put the alert in a `$nextTick` block to make sure the model updates.  The keyup event is fired before the update happens.

In `vue` you can also add a `watch`.  Much better than using key bindings.

```js
watch:{
 input(value){
  alert(value);
 }
}
```

And if you only want the value on `enter` or `blur`, use the `lazy` modifier on v-model.